# SSH tunnel bind to domain

Tags: ssh, ssl, tunnel

I have a working SSH tunnel that redirects my local calls from localhost:8080 to my remote machine on port 8080. Since I have a certificate for `*.example.com`, I am wondering if I could set up my tunnel in a way that I can use `https://example.com:8080` instead of `http://localhost:8080` - without editing the host file, just by opening my tunnel

Answer (score 1):

With `-L`, no. The ssh client cannot override how the OS performs domain resolution.

A `-D` SOCKS tunnel could do so, because it acts as a full proxy service and web browsers usually have the option to forward the domain name to the proxy instead of resolving it locally. So the ssh client could substitute the domain name and make a different connection than what the browser asked for.

But if you use `-D` tunnels, that's probably not necessary anyway, because they already allow you to enter *any* domain name and it will be proxied through SSH. As long as your x.example.com domain resolves to the server's own IP address, it will work here.

Comment: Can a SOCKS tunnel be limited only for a certain domain? All the other traffic shouldn't go over this